# Issue with Hyperledger fabric go build command

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/channel"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/event"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/ledger"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/resmgmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/common/errors/retry"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/common/providers/fab"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/core/config"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk"
)

type Degree struct {......
```

I am new to Blockchain programming and I am trying to build a degree verification application with the help of my friend. We wrote the whole program, Installed/Set Up Hyperledger Fabric, Go on Ubuntu 22.04. When we try to run it using

```
go build fabric.go (or) go run fabric.go
```

We get the following error,

> fabric.go:7:2: no required module provides package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim; to add it: go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim fabric.go:8:2: no required module provides package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer; to add it: go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer

We tried installing the required Go module dependencies as it suggested and we keep getting

> go: module github.com/hyperledger/fabric@upgrade found (v2.1.1+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim

and

go: module github.com/hyperledger/fabric@upgrade found (v2.1.1+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer

I have no idea how to proceed further and I could use your help. Please explain it as if you are explain it to a five year old, because as I said I am new to this and I am not fully versed with all the terms. I am learning fabric by making projects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see enough information in your question to see where your problem is occurring and therefore how to solve it. You should not be importing any packages from `github.com/hyperledger/fabric/...`. This is the core Fabric server implementation and it is not intended to be consumed as a library. Neither the client SDK or chaincode APIs should be importing these packages either, so I am not sure what in your code is referencing them.

If you are just learning Fabric, I would strongly recommend that you use Fabric v2.4 (or later) and use the [Fabric Gateway client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/) to build your client application instead of the legacy Go SDK. Samples linked from that documentation homepage demonstrate how to use the API to build client applications.

The [Fabric documentation on client applications](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) describes the key elements of the client application API. The in-line code examples reference the TypeScript sample but there is an identical sample implementation  in Go, and the API structure is extremely similar in all the supported client languages, so the tutorial should be useful regardless of your application language.